# requires with Thrift compiled classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thrift

Thrift's gen-rb folder and namespacing doesn't really match rails conventions about auto-loading modules with the correct folder structure.  What is the best solution or best practice to load thrift compiled classes in a Rails project?

Answer (score 0):

i use require_relative to load the files.